# Display is set to Mobile PC Display on Windows when I run it on  Macbook Pro via boot camp

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, display, resolution

Just installed Windows using boot camp. I downloaded the drivers using boot camp. After installing the display says: Mobile PC Display. I have 15 inch Macbook Pro.  What display driver do I need to get the right resolution?

**Update:** Okay. My bad. Went to Genius bar at apple they told me that Mobile PC Display is how Macbook sees your display on Windows. Resolution is 1440 x 900 what my resolution on Macbook. There is no missing driver after all.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your MacBook has a AMD Radeon HD 6490M video card per your properties screen. You'll need to download the driver from [AMD](http://www.amd.com)'s website.

**For Windows 7:**

- 64 bit: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx
- 32 bit: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-32.aspx

For your display driver you might need to update your Bootcamp drivers which you can get from Apple's [Boot Camp Support Drivers](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macoscomponents).

Comment: Do I install this when running Windows or OS X? When I try to install it on Windows AMD installer tells me "AMD Catalyst Mobility cannot be downloaded due to incompatible hardware/software on your computer.  Your computer does not contain proper graphics adapter."

Comment: I'd try running the Boot Camp update first if you haven't, that _might_ fix the compatibility problem with the AMD driver.

Comment: What do you mean by Boot Camp update? I've tried to see if there is some update button on boot camp assistant but there isn't. When I click on apple software updates it doesn't display any items for boot camp. It looks like I have most up to date boot camp version 4.0

Comment: Okay. My bad. Went to Genius bar at apple they told me that Mobile PC Display is how Macbook sees your display on Windows. Resolution is 1440 x 900 what my Macbook is configured for.